# Why does this happen IEnumerable versus List

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following BL method

```
public static void SomeMethod (List<SomeClass> group)
{
    IEnumerable<SomeClass> groupWithFalse =(from SomeClass gr in group
                                            where gr.SomeProp== false
                                            select gr);
    foreach (SomeClass grFalse in groupWithFalse)
    {
      grFalse.Save();
    }

    if (groupWithFalse.Any())
    {
      // do some stuff
    }
}
```

The mock implementation for dl saving (which cannot be changed as it used in a lot of unit tests) is:

```
public void Save()
{
   group.SomeProp = true;
}
```

If I try to unit test the last statement of the flow e.g if `(groupWithFalse.Any())` the statement fails, as apparently there are no more elements with that property set to false.
If I change the code in business logic to :

```
public static void SomeMethod (List<SomeClass> group)
{
    List<SomeClass> groupWithFalse = new List<SomeClass>();
    foreach (var g in group)
    {
      if (g.SomeProp == false)
          groupWithFalse.Add(g);
    }

    foreach (SomeClass grFalse in groupWithFalse)
    {
      grFalse.Save();
    }

    if (groupWithFalse.Any())
    {
      // do some stuff
    }
}
```

the conditional statement `if (groupWithFalse.Any())` does not fail in unit tests. Why does this happen? Thanks

Comment: Google 'linq lazy evaluation'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running a LINQ query does not store the results.
Instead, it will re-execute the query each time you enumerate it.

After calling `Save()`, the query will be empty, since none of the items meet the `where` clause.

Change it to

```
var unsaved = group.Where(g => !g.SomeProp).ToList();
```

Calling `ToList()` will store the results in a `List<T>`; this avoids re-executing the query.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is occurring because of [deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx). In your first example, `groupWithFalse` doesn't represent a list of objects where `SomeProp` is false, it refers to a query that can evaluate to said list.

If you want your list to stay put during your entire function, simply add `.ToList()` on the end of your LINQ query like so:

```
IEnumerable<SomeClass> groupWithFalse =(from SomeClass gr in group
                                        where gr.SomeProp == false
                                        select gr).ToList();
//                                                ^^^^^^^^^
```

This will cause the query to execute *immediately* and return its results into a `List<SomeClass>` whose contents *won't* change if you modify the objects within it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in [Lazy Evalution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2006/10/04/lazy-evaluation-_2800_and-in-contrast_2c00_-eager-evaluation_2900_.aspx) of LINQ. In first example, the LINQ query is actualy run TWICE. First for enumerating for calling your Save() method, and second to get Any().

As general rule while working with LINQ, put ToList() after each and every query.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, in the first implementation what is happening is that you are defining an iterator `groupWithFalse` that iterates over the elements of `group` that have `SomeProp` set to `false`. You've iterated over `groupWithFalse` and set `SomeProp` to `true` for all of those elements and now when you iterate again (the call to `Any` produces a second iteration), every element has `SomeProp` set to `true` since you just set it to be so and so of course `Any` returns `false` (the iteration produces the empty collection now).

To elaborate a little bit, basically when you say

```
IEnumerable<SomeClass> groupWithFalse =(from SomeClass gr in group
                                        where gr.SomeProp== false
                                        select gr);
```

you are defining an object (`groupWithFalse`) that captures the logic "give me a sequence of the elements in `group` that have `SomeProp` set to false." Explicitly, this object is not actually a collection or sequence of those elements for which `SomeProp` is set to false. The first time that you iterate over this object (`foreach`), this rule will produce elements for which `SomeProp` is `false` (if there are any in `group`). But when you iterate a second time (`Any`), this rule will not produce any elements because you've modified the collection `group` from which this rule draws its elements from.

In the second iteration you are checking if the `List<SomeClass>` named `groupWithFalse` is the empty collection which it is not because you've added elements to it in the `foreach` loop that immediately precedes it.

Here's how I would write your code:

```
public static void SomeMethod (List<SomeClass> group) {
    IEnumerable<SomeClass> groupWithFalse =(from SomeClass gr in group
                                            where gr.SomeProp== false
                                            select gr);
    if(groupWithFalse.Any()) {
        foreach (SomeClass grFalse in groupWithFalse) {
            grFalse.Save();
        }

        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

Now the code reads like "Get the elements of `group` for which `SomeProp` is `false`. If there are `Any`, `Save` them and then do some stuff."

Answer (score 0):

**In the first** example you are using IEnumerable. Think about it like a query, not a list of objects. So then you are iterating through entire collection "group" using above query that says "iterate only elements that have SomeProp equal to false".

Then in your foreach statement you modify the state of the object in "group" list.

And then you are applying additional predicate on you query that states "Are there **any** elements in "group" list that have some prop equal to false?" And you obviously recieve an answer "no there are none of them".

**In the second** example you just getting new collection of elements, NOT a query. So then you iterate over it, chage state and then ask "Are there **any** elements?" And recive an "yes" answer. There are the same elements as before but with changed SomeProp property value.